# Liquibase : How to include files from github dynamically based on configuration

Tags: maven, mariadb, liquibase

I want liquidbase include tag to be dynamically filled up from another file which will have link from GitHub. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I think liquibase can not do this out-of-the-box. You could maybe do it yourself by using [preconditions](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html) and implement a `<customPrecondition>` class and then download the file yourself. But just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, at least at liquibase level.

You can run some maven task to download files while building your app (possibly, in the beginning of build process, because liquibase files are being packed inside the resulting artifact), put these files in some directory, and then use liquibase's tag `<includeAll>` to include all files in the chosen directory.

Also, I don't think `preConditions` will work, even on `<databaseChangeLog>` level, because, correct me if I'm wrong, liquibase initializes files that it's supposed to include before running any `preConditions`.